# delete sql table data with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

i have stored image data in a sql table when uploading images. then i want to delete individual images with ajax.

here is my php code to retrieve images from table. there are few images.

```
while($infoi= mysqli_fetch_array($ri, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $imageId= $infoi['image_id'];
    $albumIdi= $infoi['album_id'];
    $imageName= $infoi['image_name'];
    $size= $infoi['size'];
    $type= $infoi['type'];
    $mainImage= $infoi['main_image_file_path'];
    $thumbImage= $infoi['thumb_image_file_path'];
    $addedDayi= $infoi['added_day'];


    echo '  <tr class="'.$imageId.'">
            <td> <a href="'.$mainImage.'" data-lightbox="'.$albumIdi.'">   <img src="'.$thumbImage.'" class="img-responsive thumbnail"  />    </a></td>
            <td> '.$imageName.' </td>
            <td> '.$size.' Kb  </td>
            <td>'.$addedDayi.'</td>
            <td> 
                <input type="submit" class=" btn btn-sm btn-danger ico-windows" id="'.$imageId.'" value="Delete"/>

                <div class="showResult" id="'.$imageId.'" style="display:none"> this division hided </div>
            </td> 
        </tr>
          ';  
    }// inner while
```

how i pass the image id via ajax to the php script?
in php i can use query string to pass the imageId but in ajax i have no idea to how to it.

if deleted successfully whole table row should be hided and if not deleted an error message should be showed in div class="showResult"

Comment: ajax = http request. pass it like you would any other request: `http://example.com/script.php?id=$id`, basically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send it as a get query too. You just need to append the id to your url

```
var url = url + "?imageId=" + id;
```

if you use jQuery it's very simple.

```
$("#select inputs").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://my.website.com/ajax-delete.php?imageId=" + id,
        success : function() {
            $("#" + id).hide();
        }
    });
}
```

I forget the confirm part. With jQuery you can add a callback function who can hide the element if the query succeed. I edited to add a closure.

Comment: it worked thnx. now i have another problem i posted it as an answer below plz look at it